# Python smtplib has no attribute SMTP_SSL

Tags: python, centos, smtplib

I'm try to send an email with SMTP_SSL (the mail server does not support smtp).

```
import smtp
s = smtp.SMTP_SSL('xxxxx')
```

I get an error:

> module object has no attribute 'SMTP_SSL'

I don't quite understand why python smptlib has no attribute SMTP_SSL given that the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html) shows that SMTP_SSL has this attribute.

Answer (score 5):

Either your script's name is email.py or you have another script in your directory named email.py. You should change the name of the script.

Answer (score 1):

When python is compiled without ssl support, you get an smtp module without the expected attribute: SMTP_SSL.

This happens sometimes when openssl is not automatically detected, maybe some dependency isn't installed on the system when python was built.

Here is a tutorial on how to overcome that: https://techglimpse.com/install-python-openssl-support-tutorial/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30891918)

Comment: BrokenBenchmark: would this be better:  When python is compiled without ssl/openssl support, you get an smtp module without the expected attribute: SMTP_SSL .  ? would that be ok?

Comment: Yes, along with instructions / ideas for enabling SSL support.